# Increase AWS Cognito session token

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am pretty sure I saw somewhere in AWS console which can help me increase the session expiration time of logged in user but I cannot find it ... screenshot or guide appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token expiration is configured for each App client. Go to your user pool -> App Clients -> Choose a specific app client. Like this:
[image: AWS Cognito Session Timeout]

if this is what you need.